# Facebook API - Check "visibility" of app postings

Tags: php, facebook, api

Is it possible to check which "visibility" settings the user granted for the application? When authorizing the app, the user might choose for example "public" or "only me"

Is it somehow possible through api to get information which settings the user applied? We want to reward users for our publishes on his stream, but of course only, if they are at least "friends" or "public"

If not, is it possible to force user that he can only use app, if hes setting privacy settings to "friends" or "public"?

Comment: _“We want to reward users for our publishes on his stream”_ – that would be a violation of the Platform Policies: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ – _IV. Application Integration Points_, Point 1.

Answer (score 0):

We used to use the FQL to find this information but it seems that the FQL command for this has been deprecated.

There doesn't seem to be a new API endpoint to even check.

Wonder if FB will provide one in the future?